# Attached JSONData not posting

Tags: android, json, http-post

I have went through all the related threads but i was not successful yet .
I am posting the JSON to the server using the below code . But the JSON data is not posting to the URL .

```
public static JSONObject PostJSONFromUrl(String urlString , String jsontosend ) 
    {
        Log.e(" Api-Hit urlString " , " is "+urlString);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        JSONObject json = null ;
        String tmpstr ;

        try {
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urlString);
                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsontosend);  
                se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
                post.setEntity(se);
                response = client.execute(post);

                //Checking response 
                if(response!=null)
                {
                    tmpstr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                    json = new JSONObject(tmpstr);
                }
        } 
        catch(Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.e(" Api-Hit return data " , " is "+json);
        return json;

    }
```

I don't know where i am going wrong .

I am getting the return data as JSON from the server side . I get "Invalid Data" error which is supposed to receive, if the JSON sent to the server is empty .

Thanks in Advance .

Comment: What do you mean by - "But the JSON data is not posting to the URL"? Are you getting any `Exception` or something else?

Comment: I have edited the question . I get " Invalid data " error from the server side which is supposed to receive if the JSON is empty

Comment: So `jsontosend` must be the `String` in `JSON` format.? Have you checked it, if its not null and if its a valid json?

Comment: So its Valid. Right?? and also change `se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));` by `post.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");`

Comment: post does not has .setContentType() , So i also tried "   HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urlString);
             post.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsontosend));
             post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
             post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
             response = client.execute(post);   "  but still i am getting the same error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37334/discussion-between-vignesh-and-anujmathur-07)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
      public class HttpClientService{
private String LOG_TAG = "HttpClientService";
private DefaultHttpClient httpclient;
//private String WEBSERVER_URL = "";

public HttpClientService(final Context context){
    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
            new AuthScope(null, -1),
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials("admin","pass"));
}
public JSONObject executeServiceWithParams(final String params) {
    String aURL = WEBSERVER_URL + "?" + params.replace(" ", "%20");
    //aURL = aURL.replace("\n", "");

    aURL = aURL.replace("\n", "?????");
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Service = "+ aURL);

    System.out.println("------ Service URL --------"+aURL);

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(aURL);
    try {
        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        final InputStream responseStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

        if(responseStream != null){
            final JSONObject result = getJsonObjectFromStream(responseStream);
            return result;
        }
        return null;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "exception generated while login "+ e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```